# Best way to create a drawing app which can use images as fill

Tags: swift, uiimage, drawing, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I'm trying to create a section of an app where the user can draw freestyle shapes and fill these shapes with an image.

I have tried using UIBezierPaths and CAShapeLayers, and have been able to create a drawing app which fills all images with a single colour.

I want each shape to be able to be filled with a different colour, so eventually the individual shapes can be filled with separate images.

I'm having trouble separating each drawing so they can be filled individually, and have so far been unable to fill a drawing with an image.

If anyone has suggestions of other ways I could go about doing this, I would appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about maybe using `SpriteKit` for the drawing portion of your app? Using `Spritekit` you can create your shapes using `SKShapeNode` and fill them with different colors using the `fillColor` property of `SKShapeNode`. For filling the newly create shape with an image you can place your image in an `SKSpriteNode` then crop it using `SKCropNode` and set the `maskNode` property of `SKCropNode` to the `SKShapeNode` you created.

Eample:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class DrawView: SKScene {

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //creating a triangle and filling it with the color blue
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddArc(path, nil, 160, 284, 0, 0, CGFloat(M_PI*2), true)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nill, 60, 184)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nill, 260, 184)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nill, 60, 284)

    let triangle = SKShapeNode()
    triangle.lineCap = .Round
    triangle.lineJoin = .Round
    triangle.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    triangle.path = path
    addChild(triangle)

    //placing image into SKSpriteNode
    let image = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImage")
    image.size = CGSizeMake(320, 568)
    image.position = CGPointMake(160, 284)

    //creating an SKCropNode
    let imageCrop = SKCropNode()
    imageCrop.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    imageCrop.addChild(image) //adding image to the SKCropNode
    imageCrop.maskNode = triangle //using the triangle created as a mask
    addChild(imageCrop)
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {

  //create spritekit scene
  let skView = SKView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
  skView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
  self.view.addSubview(skView)

  //add drawing view to the scene
  let drawView = DrawView()
  sKView.presentScene(drawView)
  }
}
```

The tricky part is going to be repositioning the `SKSpriteNode` and `SKCropNode` to fill the `SKShapeNode`.